# Adding separator between menu items in a table menu

Tags: html, css, menu, separator

I have a menu that's been created using a table (if possible, please provide answers that do not require me to change to a list or something else... apologies about that)

Anyway, I'd like to add a separator between the each menu item except for the item that is selected. Meaning if a menu item is selected I would like border-right to not exist. Please have a look at the attached image:

[image]

As you can see, enquiries is selected; however, the border from the knowledge menu item is still visible. Is there any way to remove this?

At the moment the css is as follows:

```
div#nav a{
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border-right: 1px solid red;
}

div#nav td.selected a{
   color: #004466;
   border-right: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="nav">
      <table id="navTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="Knowledge">Knowledge</a></td>
            <td><a href="Enquiries">Enquiries</a></td>
            <td><a href="Contact">Contact</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Are there any CSS tricks that would help me in removing the border-right of the item that's next to the 'selected' menu item? Note: if it helps I can use border-left too.

Any insight would be extremely helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: You can try it with the before and after pseudo classes of CSS3 http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: Do you tried css hover?

Comment: @Mindbreaker not sure how something like that would work. Which element would I apply the ::after class to?

Comment: @NewBiL thanks for your suggestion, can you give me some more insight on how hover would work for this? Thank you again

Comment: Could you also post your html please

Comment: @kozlovski5 Edited the post to add html

Comment: How are you adding the `selected` class to the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
div#nav a {
   border-left: 1px solid red;
}

div#nav td:first-child a, div#nav td.selected a, div#nav td.selected + td a {
   border-left: none;
}
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zitrusfrisch/WNTBH/

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! This is brilliant and helped address what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
div#nav td {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border-right: 1px solid red;
}

div#nav td.selected {
   color: #004466;
   border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, kozlovski5. Unfortunately, this did not work. I've added the html, maybe i'm missing table#navTable?

Comment: Try removing the comma in you're first statement, check my updated code replace it and see if it works

Comment: Why don't you try adding the border to the td element and then get rid of it? See if my above answer helps

Comment: It doesn't work anyway as the td before the td.selected one still has a border. You cannot get rid of it using border-right – but border-left! See my answer below (fiddle included).